# Improve Proof Writing Skills

Tags: proof-writing

I've recently delved into proof-writing contests such as the USA(J)MO, and the problems have presented a nice challenge. However, it has been challenging for me to write a neat, concise proof for many of the questions. Does anyone have tips/resources for improving one's skills in this regard? Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Practise them :)

Comment: Too broad a question. The only advice I have is solve tough problems, write proofs, and improve. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Same way you get to Carnegie Hall?

Comment: Makes sense! I guess doing more problems and reading their solutions would especially help.

Comment: This might be better suited for [Math Educators.SE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Might be worth reading: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/3873/how-to-teach-proofs and https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/19140/how-do-you-teach-students-about-the-concept-of-a-proof

Comment: Thanks for the resources!

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/news/articles/how-to-write-a-solution seen this? Evan Chen also has some PDFs on his website